# How to load/generate a separate cardview.xml into a fragment class

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

I have a fragment and I want to generate a number of card views into the fragment. First I did this programmable in java:

```
 CardView cardView = new CardView(context);
    cardView.setId(id);
    cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    cardView.setLayoutParams( new
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This way I can add as many card views as I want to the fragment. I also added an expendable button, a switch, and a table view to the card view. This all works but, my code is really messy. So I was wondering, can I have an XML template layout for by card view and load this into the Fragment Class as many times as I want, and also bind data to each card view?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my strategy. Instead of trying to generate views into the fragment, I just generate nested fragments.

**Parent Fragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.app.ssl.R;
import com.app.ssl.databinding.FragmentChildfragmentBinding;

public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentChildfragmentBinding binding;
    private  View root;

    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceStage) {
        binding = FragmentChildfragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        root = binding.getRoot();

        FragmentManager fragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();

        Fragment fragA = new NestedFragment("A");
        fragTrans.add(R.id.nested_fragment_container, fragA);
        fragTrans.addToBackStack("A");

        Fragment fragB = new NestedFragment("B");
        fragTrans.add(R.id.nested_fragment_container, fragB);
        fragTrans.addToBackStack("B");

        Fragment fragC = new NestedFragment("C");
        fragTrans.add(R.id.nested_fragment_container, fragC);
        fragTrans.addToBackStack("C");

        fragTrans.commit();
        return root;
        }
    }
```

**Child Fragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.app.ssl.R;

public class NestedFragment extends Fragment {
    private View root;
    private TextView textview;
    private String title;

    public NestedFragment(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nested, container, false);
        textview = root.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textview.setText(title);
        return root;
    }
}
```

**Parent Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ContainerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.nestedFragment.ParentFragment">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nested_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Child Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="800sp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#f1ff91"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Child fragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```